# Java error when compiling

Tags: java, compilation

Im making a Runescape private server, but im having slight problems with compiling. The code i use for my source is:

> @echo off "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\javac.exe"
>   -classpath deps/log4j-1.2.15.jar;deps/jython.jar;deps/xstream.jar;deps/mina.jar;deps/mysql.jar;deps/poi.jar;deps/slf4j.jar;deps/slf4j-nop.jar
>   -d bin src\server\event*.java src\server\model\items*.java src\server\model\minigames*.java src\server\model\npcs*.java
>   src\server\model\objects*.java src\server\model\players*.java
>   src\server\model\players\skills*.java
>   src\server\model\players\packets*.java src\server\model\shops*.java
>   src\server\net*.java src\server\task*.java src\server\util*.java
>   src\server\world*.java src\server\util\log*.java src\server*.java
>   src\server\world\map*.java src/server/gui/*.java

and for my client/auto cache i use:

> @echo off Title Compiler "C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\javac.exe" -d ./Class/ Java/*.java
>   Java/sign/*.java pause

So, i get the same error on both of the codes, and i have no clue how to fix it...
The error is:
Note: Java\client.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Hope that someone knows how to fix this :)

Comment: *i get the same error on both of the codes* what error?

Comment: That's not an error, just a warning.

Comment: Oh alright, im new to this, hehe. Could you help me fixing it ?